# Windows service using VB.NET doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows-services, ssms

**What my program supposed to do** : My goal is to create a windows service which acts as a mediator between multiple SQL databases. In total there are 3 different tables in 3 different servers In detail, when this service runs it should oversee the data in the "Table1" and copy it to the "Table2" in periodical time(every 1 minute). But tricky part is it cannot paste duplicate records, has to check for "Table2" 's ID field and validate for not pasting the same record with the same ID.[I've added a diagram for understanding purposes of what my goal is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4yyj.png)

**What I've done** : So far I've developed the code completely but the issue is it only copies data from one table(specifically "NOR_LABOR" according to the diagram I've attached) to "DEV_Test_Nor_Data" in the "MES_DEV" Database(con1 to con2). According to the diagram con1, con3, con4 are tables "NOR_LABOR", "SETTER_LABOR" and "wrap_labor" respectively. con2 is the destination which is "MES_DEV" DB.

Can anybody figure out why does other table's data(con3 to con2 & con4 to con2) won't copy?

**My code - Data Collector**

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DataCollector

    Dim con1, con2, con3, con4 As New SqlConnection
    Dim timer1 As Timers.Timer
    Dim p_oConn As New Wisys.AllSystem.ConnectionInfo
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        con1 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=NORMAC-CTMS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Normac Data;Integrated Security=true")
        con1.Open()
        con2 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=STLEDGSQL01;Database=MES_DEV;Integrated Security=true")
        con2.Open()
        con3 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=201706-SETTER1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Edge;Integrated Security=true")
        con3.Open()
        con4 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PRINTER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Wrapper Data;Integrated Security=true")
        con4.Open()

        timer1 = New Timers.Timer()
        timer1.Interval = 5000
        AddHandler timer1.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
        timer1.Enabled = True
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has started")

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        timer1.Enabled = False
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has stopped")
        con1.Close()
        con2.Close()
        con3.Close()
        con4.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim cmd1, cmd2, cmd3 As SqlCommand

        'Connecting the Normac Data table
        Dim da1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select ID, trx_date, work_order, department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hours, feet_produced, item_no, posted, labor_feet_produced from NOR_LABOR", con1)
        Dim cb1 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da1)
        Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da1.Fill(dt1)

        'Connecting the Setter_Labor table
        Dim da2 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select ID, trx_date, work_order, department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hours, labor_feet_produced, item_no, posted from Setter_Labor", con3)
        Dim cb2 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da2)
        Dim dt2 As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da2.Fill(dt2)

        'Connecting the Wrap_Labor table
        Dim da3 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select ID, trx_date, work_order, Department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hrs, job_start, job_end, qty_ordered, qty_produced, item_no, lot_no, default_bin, posted, wrapped, total_shift_hrs, check_emp, machine, operation_complete from wrap_labor", con4)
        Dim cb3 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da3)
        Dim dt3 As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da3.Fill(dt3)


        Dim i, j, k As Integer

        'Inserting into DEV_Test_Nor_Data table
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt1.Rows

            cmd1 = New SqlCommand("Insert into DEV_Test_Nor_Data values('" & dr(0) & "','" & dr(1) & "','" & dr(2) & "','" & dr(3) & "','" & dr(4) & "','" & dr(5) & "','" & dr(6) & "','" & dr(7) & "','" & dr(8) & "','" & dr(9) & "','" & dr(10) & "','" & dr(11) & "')", con2)
            i = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Next

        'Inserting into DEV_Test_Set_Lbr table
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt2.Rows

            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into DEV_Test_Set_Lbr values('" & dr(0) & "','" & dr(1) & "','" & dr(2) & "','" & dr(3) & "','" & dr(4) & "','" & dr(5) & "','" & dr(6) & "','" & dr(7) & "','" & dr(8) & "','" & dr(9) & "','" & dr(10) & "')", con2)
            j = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next

        'Inserting into DEV_Test_Wrp_Lbr table
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt3.Rows

            cmd3 = New SqlCommand("Insert into DEV_Test_Wrp_Lbr values('" & dr(0) & "','" & dr(1) & "','" & dr(2) & "','" & dr(3) & "','" & dr(4) & "','" & dr(5) & "','" & dr(6) & "','" & dr(7) & "','" & dr(8) & "','" & dr(9) & "','" & dr(10) & "','" & dr(11) & "','" & dr(12) & "','" & dr(13) & "','" & dr(14) & "','" & dr(15) & "','" & dr(16) & "','" & dr(17) & "','" & dr(18) & "','" & dr(19) & "','" & dr(20) & "')", con2)
            k = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next


        da1.Update(dt1)
        cmd1.Dispose()
        dt1.Dispose()
        da1.Dispose()

        da2.Update(dt2)
        cmd2.Dispose()
        dt2.Dispose()
        da2.Dispose()

        da3.Update(dt3)
        cmd3.Dispose()
        dt3.Dispose()
        da3.Dispose()

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Reference1]

[Reference2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DmPO.png)

[Reference3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kANhT.png)

[Reference4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5J1s.png)

Comment: Don't try to preserve the connections over the life of the application. Thanks to connection pooling, you really are better off creating a new connection each time you talk to the database. In this case, that could be once per timer tick.

Comment: Also... this looks scary vulnerable to sql injection issues. I wouldn't be surprised if your whole problem is an extra single quote in the data somewhere that would have been avoided through correct use of parameterized queries.

Comment: One more thing: an **error message** would be really useful in figuring out your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @JoelCoehoorn for the valuable advices btw there was no any error message showing only issue was the con3, con4 data was not copying to the respective tables in the new DB

Comment: There's gotta be an **exception** that gets thrown. If you don't catch it, the service will just stop. You need to catch the exception and log it's `Message` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps. It may be the parameterized queries are your entire problem.

```vb
Public Class DataCollector

    'Question text said one minute
    Private timer1 As New Timers.Timer(60000)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        AddHandler timer1.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
        timer1.Enabled = True
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has started")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        timer1.Enabled = False
        FileIO.WriteLog("Service has stopped")
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' DEV_Test_Nor_Data Table
        ProcessOneTable("DEV_Test_Nor_Data", 12,
            "Data Source=NORMAC-CTMS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Normac Data;Integrated Security=true", 
            "SELECT ID, trx_date, work_order, department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hours, feet_produced, item_no, posted, labor_feet_produced FROM NOR_LABOR"
        )

        ' DEV_Test_Set_Lbr Table
        ProcessOneTable("DEV_Test_Set_Lbr", 11, 
            "Data Source=201706-SETTER1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Edge;Integrated Security=true",
            "SELECT ID, trx_date, work_order, department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hours, labor_feet_produced, item_no, posted from Setter_Labor"
        )

        ' DEV_Test_Wrp_Lbr Table
        ProcessOneTable("DEV_Test_Wrp_Lbr", 21,
            "Data Source=PRINTER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Wrapper Data;Integrated Security=true",
            "SELECT ID, trx_date, work_order, Department, work_center, operation_no, operator, total_labor_hrs, job_start, job_end, qty_ordered, qty_produced, item_no, lot_no, default_bin, posted, wrapped, total_shift_hrs, check_emp, machine, operation_complete from wrap_labor"
        )
    End Sub

    Private EdgeConnStr As String = "Data Source=STLEDGSQL01;Database=MES_DEV;Integrated Security=true"

    Private Sub ProcessOneTable(destTableName As String, ParameterCount As Integer, sourceConnectionString AS String, sourceSql As String)
        Dim data As New DataTable()
        Using sourceConn As New SqlConnection(sourceConnectionString), _
              da As New SqlDataAdapter(sourceSql, sourceConn)
            da.Fill(data)
        End Using

        Dim paramList As String = String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, ParameterCount).Select(Function(p) $"@p{p}"))
        ' Assumes first parateter (@p0) is always the ID.
        Dim sql As String = $"INSERT INTO {destTableName} SELECT {paramList} WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM {destTableName} WHERE ID = @p0)"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(EdgeConnStr), _
              cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

            For i As Integer = 0 To ParameterCount - 1
                cmd.Parameters.Add($"@p{i}", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            Next i
        
            cn.Open()
            For Each dr As DataRow In data.Rows
                For i As Integer = 0 to ParameterCount - 1
                    cmd.Parameters(i).Value = dr(i)
                Next i
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next dr
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

It sounds like you also need to worry about **merging** the data, but start with this anyway; it fixes the **HUGE GAPING SECURITY ISSUE** in the original code, as well as isolating the important part of the code down to the minimum possible method size. This will make it easier to refactor *just that part* to also worry about what IDs may already exist... but I'll let you make an attempt at that yourself first (hint: `INSERT + SELECT + WHERE NOT EXISTS()` all in the same query)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I've tried this code by replacing mine but for some reason it did not work. By the way I think I found the query to avoid duplicate ID's, 

INSERT INTO {destTableName} SELECT * FROM NOR_LABOR WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM NOR_LABOR WHERE NOR_LABOR.ID = destTableName.ID)

Also do you know a solution to make the code work? Thank you very much!

Comment: I know I should be more specific when I say the code doesn't work. Sorry about that. So the windows service starts and stops without any issue. But now no data copying from any tables. That's the issue specifically. Thanks

Comment: There's gotta be an **exception** thrown. You want to capture and log this exception.

Comment: I just checked multiple locations for any clue while letting the windows service run. Windows Event Viewer and SMSS Log File Viewer. Both doesn't show any errors. Also I'm currently running a trace using SQL Server Profiler but haven't finished yet. Will let you know if there's any exceptions.

Comment: You have to use a Try/Catch and log them yourself.

Comment: Got it, this was the error message : Exception: 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: So now you know: something is wrong connecting to Sql Server. It usually means the connection string is not right, but it could also be a firewall issue, permissions issue, or configuration issue on the server. Go debug that.

Comment: Managed to debug the sql connection, yes it was my login issue since the DB's were from network. But now I'm ended up with this exception, 

"The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects."

Searched about this exception and some says to add ".ToString" to the adding parameters part, where should I exactly add that? Or maybe another option to do? Thanks much @Joel

Comment: I tried adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but still not luck

Comment: @MegaTrone Joel's code is using the .Add(Object) overload of the parameters collection. From the docs "Add(Object) 
Adds the specified SqlParameter object to the SqlParameterCollection. As you can see the Object must be an SqlParemeter objec, not a String.

Comment: @Mary I've tried modifying "cmd.Parameters(i).Value = dr(i)" to "cmd.Parameters(i).Value = dr(i).Value.ToString()" but still it's giving me the same error. Do you have any suggestion? Please and thank you!

Comment: The error is **"Error locating Server"**. Right now you can't even make the connection, and you won't get anywhere until you figure that out. Most likely something is wrong in the connection string.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the current exception throwing is "The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects." and I managed to debug the "Error locating Server" exception. Thanks

Comment: To me seems like when the code tries to add null-values to the table the exception occurs, did a good research and modified the code accordingly,

1. Tried adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
2. Modified "cmd.Parameters.Add($"@p{i}")" to cmd.Parameters.Add($"@p{i}").ToString()
3. Modified "cmd.Parameters(i).Value = dr(i)" to "cmd.Parameters(i).Value = dr(i).Value.ToString()"

still no luck.

Comment: @MegaTrone Have you tried Joel's edited code? Specifically `cmd.Parameters.Add($"@p{i}", SqlDbType.VarChar)`. Note the addition of `,SqlDbType.VarChar`. This satisfy the `.Add` method with `(String, SqlDbType)` overload.